# IntentService started twice

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, intentservice

I have used `IntentSerivce` to download a large json. I have used `Gson` and `Retrofit2` in the first place. After I have found that `Jackson` is better for marshaling of large json.

And here problem starts, `intentService` has been triggered twice even in code is called only once.

I am triggering `intentService` from splash screen, the orientation of the device is landscape. There are no flipping up/down so I guess that there is no recreation of activity when orientation is changed. Also app is hardcoded to start in landscape orientation.

Here are logs from logCat

```
 I/APPLICATION CLASS: DB FOUND
02-28 10:15:25.034 1561-2108/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=aoc.netcast.rs.android_ott_client/.view.SplashScreen} from uid 10073 on display 0
```

> 02-28 10:15:25.040 3195-3195/? I/INTENT PERFORMING: Starting intent...
>
> 02-28 10:15:25.041 3195-3195/? I/INTENT PERFORMING: Intent started...

```
02-28 10:15:25.053 1206-1286/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-28 10:15:25.062 3195-3210/? W/nAnnotationIntrospector: Unable to load JDK7 annotation types; will have to skip
```

> 02-28 10:15:25.074 3195-3195/? I/INTENT PERFORMING: Starting intent...
>
> 02-28 10:15:25.074 3195-3195/? I/INTENT PERFORMING: Intent started...

```
02-28 10:15:25.090 3195-3210/? W/System.err: WARNING: could not load Java7 Path class
02-28 10:15:25.330 1206-1206/? E/SurfaceFlinger: rejecting buffer: bufWidth=1080, bufHeight=1920, front.active.{w=1080, h=1776}

                                                 [ 02-28 10:15:25.341  3195: 3209 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fa7db557360, tid 3209
02-28 10:15:25.344 3195-3209/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-28 10:15:25.344 1561-1612/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
02-28 10:15:25.344 1561-1612/? I/InputReader: Device reconfigured: id=0, name='qwerty2', size 1080x1920, orientation 1, mode 1, display id 0
02-28 10:15:25.350 1694-2096/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7fa7cf1b1b10
02-28 10:15:25.353 1694-2096/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 2096: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
02-28 10:15:25.353 1694-2096/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fa7ce77fa80, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
02-28 10:15:25.365 3195-3209/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 3209: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
02-28 10:15:25.365 3195-3209/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fa7db548c40, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
02-28 10:15:25.367 1694-2096/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7fa7cf1b23d0
02-28 10:15:25.378 1694-2096/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 2096: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
02-28 10:15:25.378 1694-2096/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fa7ce77fac0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
02-28 10:15:25.449 1561-1580/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed aoc.netcast.rs.android_ott_client/.view.SplashScreen: +390ms (total +578ms)
02-28 10:15:25.458 1561-1580/? I/WindowManager: Screen frozen for +559ms due to Window{85b86c9 u0 aoc.netcast.rs.android_ott_client/aoc.netcast.rs.android_ott_client.view.SplashScreen}
02-28 10:15:27.461 1561-1580/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Explicit
02-28 10:15:27.471 1561-1580/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14571(904KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 31% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 127us total 9.460ms
02-28 10:15:30.335 1561-2989/? I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
```

I don't know why is this happening, can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: Post the code where from you start the service.

Comment: I think that I have found the source of the problem. I have tested on TV emulator and found that intent has been started just once. So I figured it out  when android is starting the application, it will fire up in portrait mode first and then after it will check if the orientation needs to be changed. While changing orientation of the screen activity will be recreated and that is the reason why I have two intents started.